# Console project and winforms project in the same solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I have a winforms that gathers information from users and updates some SQL-Server tables.

I have a console which runs on a remote server and is scanning the same tables; given certain criteria in the tables this console completes several processes.

Currently the console and winforms do not need to talk to each other.

Should I place both projects in the same Solution or in two separate Solutions?

Comment: Place them in the same solution as different projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single solution. For more info you should read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817674.aspx) (section **Partitioning Solutions and Projects**)

**Advantages**

The single solution model offers the following advantages:

- When you need to reference another assembly generated by a separate
  project, you can use a project reference. Project references are the
  preferred way to establish references to other assemblies and they
  are guaranteed to work on all development workstations in a team
  environment. The many advantages of project references and guidance
  on when to use file references are discussed in Referencing
  Assemblies in Chapter 4, "Managing Dependencies."
- Assembly versioning issues are avoided, because Visual Studio .NET
  detects when a client of a referenced assembly needs to be rebuilt.
- Project references are sensitive to changes in the configuration of
  the referenced project. This means that you can automatically switch
  from Debug and Release builds across projects without having to reset
  references.
- The system build process and build script is much simpler.

**Disadvantages**

You are advised to adopt the single solution model whenever possible. However:

- The model scales only so far. If you want to work on a single project within the solution, you are forced to acquire all of the source code for all projects within the solution.
- Even minor (nonbreaking) changes to a single source file within a single project can result in a rebuild of many projects within the solution, due to project dependencies. If an assembly's interface changes within a referenced project, you want the client project to be rebuilt. However, unnecessary rebuilds can be very time consuming, especially for solutions containing many projects.